# How to take only one connection from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have a matrix, like the below one

```
       ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4 ID_8 ID_5 ID_7 ID_100
ID_1      0    1    1    1  Inf    2    2    Inf
ID_2      1    0    2    1  Inf    1    2    Inf
ID_3      1    2    0    2  Inf    3    1    Inf
ID_4      1    1    2    0  Inf    2    1    Inf
ID_8    Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    0  Inf  Inf      1
ID_5      2    1    3    2  Inf    0    3    Inf
ID_7      2    2    1    1  Inf    3    0    Inf
ID_100  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    1  Inf  Inf      0
```

I used `as.data.frame.table` and `filter` because I want only those values that have 3. The output look likes

```
  nodeA nodeB score
1  ID_5  ID_3     3
2  ID_3  ID_5     3
3  ID_7  ID_5     3
4  ID_5  ID_7     3
```

The code I wrote

```
mat_pi_lon <- as.data.frame.table(mat, responseName = "score") %>%
  filter(score ==3) %>%
  rename(nodeA = Var1, nodeB = Var2)
```

But, my actual expected output is like the below one. Because, `ID_3 ID_5 3 and ID_5 ID_3 3` are same (in terms of concept). So, I want only `ID_3 ID_5 3` not `ID_5 ID_3 3`.

```
  nodeA nodeB score
1  ID_3  ID_5     3
2  ID_5  ID_7     3
```

Is it possible to reduce the output?

Reproducible Data

```
structure(c(0, 1, 1, 1, Inf, 2, 2, Inf, 1, 0, 2, 1, Inf, 1, 2, 
Inf, 1, 2, 0, 2, Inf, 3, 1, Inf, 1, 1, 2, 0, Inf, 2, 1, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 0, Inf, Inf, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, Inf, 0, 3, Inf, 
2, 2, 1, 1, Inf, 3, 0, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1, Inf, Inf, 
0), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", 
"ID_4", "ID_8", "ID_5", "ID_7", "ID_100"), c("ID_1", "ID_2", 
"ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_8", "ID_5", "ID_7", "ID_100")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare character strings with `<=` but not factors. So, coerce `Var1` and `Var2` to character before filtering all `Var1 > Var2` out.

```
library(dplyr)

mat %>% as.data.frame.table(responseName = "score") %>%
  mutate(Var1 = as.character(Var1),
         Var2 = as.character(Var2)) %>%
  filter(score == 3 & Var1 <= Var2) %>%
  rename(nodeA = Var1, nodeB = Var2)
#  nodeA nodeB score
#1  ID_3  ID_5     3
#2  ID_5  ID_7     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may `replace` the `upper.tri` with `NA` first and thereby save a few steps.

```
library(dplyr)
mat %>%
  replace(., upper.tri(.), NA) %>%
  as.data.frame.table(responseName="score") %>%
  filter(score %in% 3)
#   Var1 Var2 score
# 1 ID_5 ID_3     3
# 2 ID_7 ID_5     3
```

Using base R:

```
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- NA
d <- as.data.frame.table(mat, responseName="score")
d[d$score %in% 3, ]
#    Var1 Var2 score
# 22 ID_5 ID_3     3
# 47 ID_7 ID_5     3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmin/pmax` to rearrange the elements by row and use `duplicated` to remove the duplicate elements

```
library(dplyr)
mat_pi_lon %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(cbind(pmin(as.character(nodeA), 
            as.character(nodeB)),
        pmax(as.character(nodeA), as.character(nodeB)))))
#  nodeA nodeB score
#1  ID_5  ID_3     3
#2  ID_7  ID_5     3
```

---

Or use `base R` in a one-liner

```
subset(mat_pi_lon, !duplicated(t(apply(mat_pi_lon, 1, sort))))
#   nodeA nodeB score
#1  ID_5  ID_3     3
#3  ID_7  ID_5     3
```