# At vector.pmt:444 : cannot reserve space for vector, Out of memory

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large graph (`vertex# 9,634 and edges# 454,691`). I am using `shortest.paths()` function to get the shortest path matrix.

But, unfortunately, I am getting an error, `At vector.pmt:444 : cannot reserve space for vector, Out of memory`.

I am using `R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)`
`Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`
`Memory: 64 GB`

Sample code is given below:

```
test <- read.csv("~/data.csv")
g1 <- test[1:5,]
graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(g1, directed = FALSE)
E(graph1)$weight <- is.numeric(g1$weight)

mat_1 <- shortest.paths(graph1) # getting error in this line
```

I have gone through several posts and found one piece of information [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-06/msg00018.html) but this code is not fulfilling my purpose. I need the whole matrix and then I have to do some filter in this matrix. For example, after getting the whole matrix, I will take only the cell values which have `2`. Regarding filtering, I have another post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507728/how-to-take-only-one-connection-from-a-matrix).

Badly need your help and suggestion.

For your kind information: I am also trying to use 87GB in a `cluster` but getting the same error!

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446633/apparently-not-justified-vector-pmt444-cannot-reserve-space-for-vector-out

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yes, the same type of problems. No answer in this post! Moreover, the post you have comparing 2 different packages and but I am using only 1 package

Comment: I doubt that anyone can guess their way to a solution. Error conditions require better descriptions for good answers. That's why there's a specific close-vote justification that we can pick from a menu.

Comment: Just tried this with simulated data of the same size - it only used 2GB of ram and a few minutes of computing time. You'll need to provide a reproducible example to get any useful help I think.

Comment: @pseudospin could you tell me, how much RAM do you have? How you checked that it took only 2GB?

Comment: @IRTFM I am thinking about how can I give a good description. I know for getting an answer I have to describe clearly. But, the code is working fine for the small graph but showing the error for the large graph!

Comment: @Akib62 just check task manager or activity monitor. The rsession grabbed 2GB early on and it seemed to work within that. A 10000 by 10000 matrix uses about 800MB, and the shortest distance algorithm itself should use a negligible amount of memory on top of that. Try running with your data for increasing sizes of data till it breaks. Also, did you mean `as.numeric`?

Comment: I apologize, I have an error with my dataset. Actually, my dataset contains 4 columns instead of 3 columns and that's why I was getting errors.